# Css With Master Page C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, contentplaceholder

I'm trying to add a css into my master page but not working when i put it into contentplaceholder tag.

Can someone explain me why it happen?

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>XXX</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

When i use like that it not working my style.css, bootstrap working fine.
But when i put it (style.css) out  of my contentplaceholder, it work's fine.

Why?

**CSS FILE**

```
footer
{
    background-color:Black;
}
```

**FOOTER INTO BODY**

```
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>
                Mapa do Site</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Anuncie</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Veículos Anunciados</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                XXX 2015. Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: How can u say its not working ? May it is overridden by some other css classes.

Comment: No, i'm working with the footer tag, not overriden anything

Comment: Why are you writing code in content place holder in master page? That is supposed to be pushed from child page, right?

Comment: Does it work if you change the order of stylesheet link elements, so that the style.css is after the bootstrap and bootstrap-theme css elements?

Answer (score 0):

This not a perfect solution but try...

```
footer
{
    background-color:Black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've founded my error.

When i put all my css and js into my contentplaceholder in master page, it's passive of substitution from another page that use that master page.

Than i needed to put it out from contentplaceholder and change the path of the file with "../" at the begin.

Now it looks like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>XXX</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```